# Selecting rows from one table using values gotten from another table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have currently have 2 mysql tables in my db

`Film` and `Film_Ratings_Report`

The primary key for Film is `filmid` which is used to identify the film ratings in the `Film_Ratings_Report` table.

I would like to know if its possible using a MYSQL query only to search the ratings table and collect all film ids which fit a certain criteria then use the selected IDs to get the film titles from the Film table. Below is the MYSQL query Im using which isnt working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM film 
UNION SELECT filmid 
      FROM film_rating_report 
      WHERE rating = 'GE' 
      LIMIT 0,0
```

I am relatively green to MYSQL and would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM film WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT filmid FROM film_rating_report WHERE rating = 'GE');
```

should work

Answer (score 16):

It seems you want a **[semi-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29)**, e.g. a join where only data from one of the 2 joined tables are needed. In this case, all rows from `film` for which there is a matching row in `film_rating_report` that has the wanted condition (`rating = 'GE'`).

This is not exactly equivalent to a usual join because even if there are 2 (or more) row in the second table (2 ratings of a film, both with `'GE'`), we still want the film to be shown once, not twice (or more times) as it would be shown with a usual join.

There are various ways to write a semi-join and most popular are:

- using an `EXISTS` correlated subquery ([@Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399835/selecting-rows-from-one-table-using-values-gotten-from-another-table-mysql/17400014#17400014)):

  ```
  SELECT t1.* 
  FROM film t1 
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT filmid 
                FROM film_rating_report t2
                WHERE t2.rating = 'GE'
                AND t2.filmid = t1.id);
  ```
- using an `IN` (uncorrelated) subquery ([@SG 86's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399835/selecting-rows-from-one-table-using-values-gotten-from-another-table-mysql/17399950#17399950)):
  (this should be used with extreme care as it may return unexpected results - or none at all - if the joining columns (the two `filmid` in this case) are Nullable)

  ```
  SELECT * 
  FROM film 
  WHERE id IN 
    ( SELECT filmid 
      FROM film_rating_report 
      WHERE rating = 'GE'
    );
  ```
- using a usual `JOIN` with a `GROUP BY` to avoid the duplicate rows in the results ([@Tomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399835/selecting-rows-from-one-table-using-values-gotten-from-another-table-mysql/17400007#17400007)):
  (and note that this specific use of `GROUP BY` works in MySQL only and in recent versions of Postgres, if you ever want to write a similar query in other DBMS, you'll have to include all columns: `GROUP BY f.filmid, f.title, f.director, ...`)

  ```
  SELECT f.*
  FROM film AS f
      JOIN film_rating_report AS frr
           ON f.filmid = frr.filmid
  WHERE frr.rating = 'GE' 
  GROUP BY f.filmid ;
  ```
- A variation on @Tomas'es answer, where the `GROUP BY` is done on a derived table and then the `JOIN`:

  ```
  SELECT f.*
  FROM film AS f
      JOIN 
          ( SELECT filmid
            FROM film_rating_report
            WHERE rating = 'GE'
            GROUP BY filmid
          ) AS frr
        ON f.filmid = frr.filmid ;
  ```

Which one to use, depends on the RDBMS and the specific version you are using (for example, `IN` subqueries should be avoided in most versions of MySQL as they may produce inefficient execution plans), your specific table sizes, distribution, indexes, etc.

I usually prefer the `EXISTS` solution but it never hurts to first test the various queries with the table sizes you have or expect to have in the future and try to find the best query-indexes combination for your case.

---

Addition:  if there is a unique constraint on the `film_rating_report (filmid, rating)` combination, which means that no film will ever get two same ratings, or if there is an even stricter (but more plausible) unique constraint on `film_rating_report (filmid)` that means that every film has at most one rating, you can simplify the `JOIN` solutions to (and get rid of all the other queries):

```
    SELECT f.*
    FROM film AS f
        JOIN film_rating_report AS frr
             ON f.filmid = frr.filmid
    WHERE frr.rating = 'GE' ;
```

Comment: @Tomas thnx for your kind words.

Comment: please correct the additional note, you made a mistake by saying *"unique constraint on the (filmid, rating) combination"* when you wanted to say "unique constraint on the filmid in the film_rating_report table" :-)

Comment: **I have tested your claims about efficiency and have different results:**  the `IN` subquery is actually the fastest (1.73 sec), `EXISTS` 1.90 sec and "join & group by" the slowest - 3.91 sec. MySQL version 5.1.52. And as of MySQL 5.6, the [semi-join queries written using `IN` are even further optimized](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/semi-joins.html). And based on my test, maybe your information of `IN` being inefficient is already outdated?

Comment: MySQL 5.6 has several optimizer improvements, yes. MariaDB 5.3 and 5.5 has also several improvements on the optimizer. (as I said in the amswer, `IN` has issues is many versions, perhaps I should edit to clearly state which.) About the results you have in 5.1, what indexes were there when you did the test? I suppose you had an ndex on `film(filmid)` but was there an index on `film_rating_report(rating, filmid)` or on `film_rating_report(filmid,ratingid)` (or both?) and which was chosen by the optimizer? How big were the tables and what were the execution plans?

Answer (score 3):

Preferred solution for this is to use `join`, and don't forget `group by` so that you don't have duplicate lines:

```
select film.*
from film
join film_rating_report on film.filmid = film_rating_report.filmid
        and rating = 'GE'
group by film.filmid
```

EDIT: as correctly noted by @ypercube, I was wrong claiming that the performance of join & group by is better than using subqueries with `exists` or `in` - quite the opposite.

Comment: I haven't downvoted but the complicated `LEFT JOIN / IS NOT NULL` you have provided is equivalent to a simpler `INNER JOIN` (without `IS NOT NULL`.) And the claim that `LEFT JOINs` are always better than `IN` and `EXISTS` subqueries look awkward, too. Any justification/links for this claim?

Comment: @ypercube thanks! I use left join's so often that I forgot that this can be done using normal one :-) Well, as for the subqueries, it is always better to do it in one query using join on indices, as the subquery might involve creating temporary tables etc.

Comment: Still, I'd usually write a semi-join with `EXISTS`, not `JOIN - GROUP BY` (which is needed as you correctly stated.) This (group by) adds an overhead so it's better to be tested against the `EXISTS` version, in the specific MySQL version and table size, etc.

Comment: @ypercube: what is *"semi-join with `EXISTS`"*? What is *semi-join*? Can you please post it as separate answer?

Comment: I meant: I'd write a [semi-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29), using EXISTS, not using JOIN-GROUP BY.

Comment: @ypercube I don't understand the difference between *semi-join* and normal (left) join. Can you please post SQL code?

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM film t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT filmid 
              FROM film_rating_report t2
              WHERE t2.rating = 'GE'
              AND t2.filmid = t1.id);
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will work, thought without knowing your DB structure (consider giving SHOW CREATE TABLE on your tables), I have no way to know for sure:

```
SELECT film.*
FROM (film)
LEFT JOIN film_rating_report ON film.filmid = film_rating_report.filmid AND film_rating_report.rating = 'GE'
WHERE film_rating_report.filmid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY film.filmid
```

(The **WHERE film_rating_report.filmid IS NOT NULL** prevents lines that don't have the rating you are seeking from sneaking in, I added **GROUP BY** at the end because **film_rating_report** might match more than once - not sure as I have visibility to the data stored in it)

Comment: you have to use `group by`, because there might be duplicate lines in the reports table