# mysql return rows from table 1 based on values in either column 1 or column 2 in table 2

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables: 'tasknotes' and 'relatedtasks'.

I want to return all the rows from 'tasknotes' in which the values in its'task_id' column corresponds to the values held in one of two columns in the 'relatedtasks' table. The columns from the 'relatedtasks' table which hold these values are called 'primarytaskid' and 'relatedtaskid'

I want to return values from the 'tasknotes' if the 'tasknotes.task_id' matches the value stored in either relatedtasks.primarytaskid or relatedtasks.relatedtaskid

I tried to do it several ways. I've been looking at the example here as I thought it might help: 
[Selecting rows from one table using values gotten from another table MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399835/selecting-rows-from-one-table-using-values-gotten-from-another-table-mysql)

But I can't get it quite right. I've also tried the following but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
"Select * from tasknotes WHERE tasknotes.task_id = ? AND relatedtasks.primarytaskid = ?  OR  relatedtasks.relatedtaskid= ?";
```

How should I be dong this? I recognise an option would be to create a version of this code:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM film t1  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT filmid 
         FROM film_rating_report t2
          WHERE t2.rating = 'GE'
          AND t2.filmid = t1.id);
```

which is from the other stack answer I cited and then run it twice targeting each column distinctly, but there must be a better solution.

********** RESOLVED CODE *****************

Thanks to the answer and comments below the final code is:

```
String sql = "SELECT t.* "
            + "FROM tasknotes t "
            + "INNER JOIN relatedtasks r "
            + "ON (t.task_id = r.primarytaskid OR t.task_id = r.relatedtaskid) "
            + "WHERE r.primarytaskid=? OR r.relatedtaskid=?";
```

the values for the '?' as passed in from statements in the java code.

Comment: syntax error. thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for a `JOIN` with a nontrivial `ON` clause.

Try something like this:

```
 SELECT t.* 
   FROM tasknotes t
   JOIN relatedtasks r 
             ON (t.task_id = r.primarytask OR t.task_id = r.relatedtaskid)
```

Using `JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN` will suppress the rows from `tasknotes` that don't meet the `ON` clause.

If you need to filter, append a `WHERE` clause to the query. For example:

```
 SELECT t.* 
   FROM tasknotes t
   JOIN relatedtasks r 
             ON (t.task_id = r.primarytask OR t.task_id = r.relatedtaskid)
  WHERE t.task_id = ?
```

The trick here:

All the `FROM / JOIN ON` stuff is to be considered a chunk of code. It specifies the table (physical or virtual) in your query.  In your query your virtual table is

```
   FROM tasknotes t
   JOIN relatedtasks r 
             ON (t.task_id = r.primarytask OR t.task_id = r.relatedtaskid)
```

This virtual table has both `tasknotes` and `relatedtasks` columns in it. It has all possible combinations of rows from the two tables that match the `ON` clause.

(If you did `FROM a JOIN b` without an `ON` clause you would get all combinations of rows in `a` and `b`. That could be a great many rows.)

You put a `SELECT` clause before your virtual table to **choose the columns** you want to retrieve from that virtual table.

You put a `WHERE` clause after it to **choose the rows** you want from your virtual table.

In your case you may need `SELECT DISTINCT t.*` because your virtual table will have a row for each row in tasknotes times each matching row in `relatedtasks`.

Finally you let the query planner in MySQL figure out how to satisfy your query efficiently.

Comment: Thanks. This nearly works. I just need to situate the '?' with a WHERE clause to make it complete. Will try now

Comment: @JayBlack Add your WHERE clause after the ON statement for the JOIN.  Also, while the default behavior for JOIN in MySQL is INNER JOIN it is a good practice to explicitly include it in you script.

Comment: @user7396598: the inclusion of the keyword `INNER` is superfluous noise, it has no effect. Describing it as "default behavior" isn't quite right, bare `JOIN` can also default to "cross join". Including the `INNER` keyword doesn't provide any useful information to the future reader. Inclusion of the `CROSS` keyword is also entirely optional, but it does serve as an indication (to the future reader) that the omission of an `ON` clause was intentional. (Other databases require the CROSS keyword when the ON clause is omitted. No databases require the INNER keyword.)

Comment: Please see my explanatory edit. And by the way the choice of `INNER JOIN` or `JOIN` is a matter of personal taste. I like `JOIN`, but I really couldn't tell you why.

Comment: Thanks both. I'll post the final resolved statement in my question so it's there for reference for anyone else.

Comment: INNER and CROSS are synonyms in MySQL.  If you ever work with other databases it is better to be in the habit of being explicit because those defaults may be different.  I was encouraging a good habit to prevent confusion.  Also, an explicit identifier is never superfluous noise.  It will prevent the next developer from needing to know what the default for the application is, or guessing whether you intended default behavior or not.